# Command for today's date in two specific formats (12 Dec 17 and 12 December 2017)

Tags: datetime, date, isodate

I want to be able to just type either the short version or long version by a command, like `\longtoday` and `\shorttoday`. Some more examples of short dates are 12 May 17 and 01 Jan 07, long dates are the same, except written out months and years, 12 May 2017 and 01 January 2007.

I was thinking of using `isodate`, but I can't figure out how it works quite that well. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Possibly related (?) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390693/datetime-ranges-using-datetime2/390738#390738

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `datetime2`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\DTMusemodule{english}{en-GB}
\DTMnewdatestyle{long}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \number##3~\DTMenglishmonthname{##2}~\number##1\relax
  }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\DTMnewdatestyle{short}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \number##3~\DTMenglishshortmonthname{##2}~\number##1\relax
  }%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\newcommand{\longtoday}{{\DTMsetdatestyle{long}\today}}
\newcommand{\shorttoday}{{\DTMsetdatestyle{short}\today}}

\begin{document}

\longtoday

\shorttoday

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following should do.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\defdate[3]{% Just for testing purpose
  \day=#1\relax
  \month=#2\relax
  \year=#3\relax
  \ignorespaces}

\def\JayLaoneShortyear#1#2#3\relax{%
  #3}
\def\JayLaoneDayTWODIGITS#1#2\relax{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    0#1%
  \else
    #1#2%
  \fi}

\newcommand*{\shorttoday}{%
  \expandafter\JayLaoneDayTWODIGITS\number\day\relax\space
  \ifcase\month
    \or Jan%
    \or Feb%
    \or Mar%
    \or Apr%
    \or May%
    \or Jun%
    \or Jul%
    \or Aug%
    \or Sep%
    \or Oct%
    \or Nov%
    \or Dec\fi
  \space
  \expandafter\JayLaoneShortyear\number\year\relax
}
\newcommand*{\longtoday}{%
  \expandafter\JayLaoneDayTWODIGITS\number\day\relax\space
  \ifcase\month
    \or January%
    \or February%
    \or March%
    \or April%
    \or May%
    \or June%
    \or July%
    \or August%
    \or September%
    \or October%
    \or November%
    \or December\fi
    \space
    \number\year
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\defdate{1}{12}{2018}
\shorttoday\\
\longtoday\\
\defdate{7}{1}{2010}
\shorttoday\\
\longtoday\\
\defdate{17}{1}{2009}
\shorttoday\\
\longtoday
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another (but shorter) method with `datetime2`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\newcommand{\longtoday}{{\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr=false,ord=omit}\today}}
\newcommand{\shorttoday}{{\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr,ord=omit}\today}}

\begin{document}

\longtoday

\shorttoday

\end{document}
```

[image: 13 December 2017 13 Dec 2017]

If the date needs to appear in the PDF bookmarks, then you need to set the style before the sectioning command. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% default setting:
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr=false,ord=omit}

\begin{document}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr}
\section{\today}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr=false}
\section{\today}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of PDF showing bookmarks]

Similarly for any other expandable context, such as writing the date to an external file.

If you want to ensure two-digit day of month (without an ordinal suffix):

```
\renewcommand*{\DTMenglishordinal}[1]{\DTMtwodigits{#1}}
```