# How to get the datetime2 package to display dates in South African format: "1 April 2018"

Tags: datetime, datetime2, locale

By default Latex formats the date as `mmm d, yyyy`, i.e. in the nonsensical middle endian format.
I would like to display it as `d Mmm yyyy`, e.g. `1 April 2018`.

I've gone through the `datetime2` documentation, but there is no `dmmmyyyy` option. I also have no luck using the `babel` package, because these is no english-za localization.

*I would really like to avoid having to use the `babel` package, I have enough packages as is and I do not like the manipulations babel performs to the .aux file.*

The following code illustrates the issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%I'd really like to just specify:
%\usepackage[d\space\Mmm\space\yyyy]{datetime2}
%So I can drop the day or rearrange things as needed
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}

%opening
\title{Test} 
\author{Johan}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405942/36296 what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that works, except that XeLatex now recompiles my project 5 times :-<

Answer (score 5):

The regionless `english` style defaults to the US style (to match the default `\today` provided by the LaTeX kernel). The [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2-english) module comes with a number of predefined English-speaking locales. It currently doesn't include South African, but the `en-MT` (Malta) locale matches your required format:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[en-MT]{datetime2}

\title{Test}
\author{Johan}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: Test Johan 27 June 2018]

You can also obtain them same result with some of the other locales. For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{ord=omit}

\title{Test}
\author{Johan}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following fixes the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}

\let\oldtoday\today
\newcommand{\longtoday}{{\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr=false,ord=omit}\oldtoday}}
\newcommand{\shorttoday}{{\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr,ord=omit}\oldtoday}}
\renewcommand{\today}{{\longtoday}}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
%\longtoday

%\shorttoday

\end{document}
```

A simple alternative that does not use any packages (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112949/136037) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\today}{\ifnum\number\day<10 0\fi \number\day \space%
  \ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
  \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi \space%
  \number \year} 
\begin{document}
  \today
\end{document}
```

Comment: Rather than saving `\oldtoday` you could just use `\DTMtoday` instead (which is `datetime2`'s actual definition of `\today` provided in case another package changes `\today` after `datetime2`).