# Extract year, month, day from datetime2

Tags: datetime2

I have made a command that looks like this:

```
\newcommand*{\numdash}{\,--\,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dateRange}{mmmmmm}
    {
        \str_case:nnF { #1 }
        {
        {#4}  { 
            \str_case:nnF { #2 }
            {
            {#5}  { 
                \str_case:nnF { #3 }
                {
                {#6}  { \DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1} }%
                }{\DTMordinal{#3}{}{}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
            }
            }{\DTMordinal{#3}~\DTMmonthname{#2}%
            {}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
        }
        }{\DTMdisplaydate{#1}{#2}{#3}{-1}{}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It displays the duration from one date to the next in a succinct matter. See the image below.

[image]

However, I need to manipulate the end date by incrementing it by a few days. 
Something like `\dateRange{2016}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31 + 1}` does not work. 
I found the following code

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318006/add-n-days-to-variable-date
\DTMsavedate{DeadLineDate}{2016-05-20}
\newcommand{\DeadLineDateExtend}{1}

\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\dueDate}[1]{%
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{DeadLineDate}{#1}\daycount
    \DTMsavejulianday{newDeadLineDate}{\number\daycount}
    \DTMusedate{newDeadLineDate}
 }
```

Which can add days to a `DTMdate`. My problem is making these two functions work together.

1. Rewrite `dateRange` so that it inputs two `DTMdates` instead of the plain numbers.
2. Exctract the *year*, *month* and *date* from `newDeadLineDate` and insert it back into `dateRange`

So what I need help with is to first have two dates, increment one of them and display the daterange using `\dateRange` function. Any help with 1. or 2. from the list above is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[en-GB,calc]{datetime2}

\usepackage{xparse}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390693/datetime-ranges-using-datetime2/390738
\newcommand*{\numdash}{\,--\,}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dateRange}{mmmmmm}
    {
        \str_case:nnF { #1 }
        {
        {#4}  { 
            \str_case:nnF { #2 }
            {
            {#5}  { 
                \str_case:nnF { #3 }
                {
                {#6}  { \DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1} }%
                }{\DTMordinal{#3}{}{}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
            }
            }{\DTMordinal{#3}~\DTMmonthname{#2}%
            {}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
        }
        }{\DTMdisplaydate{#1}{#2}{#3}{-1}{}\numdash{}\DTMdisplaydate{#4}{#5}{#6}{-1}}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318006/add-n-days-to-variable-date
\DTMsavedate{DeadLineDate}{2016-05-20}
\newcommand{\DeadLineDateExtend}{1}

\newcount\daycount
\newcommand{\dueDate}[1]{%
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{DeadLineDate}{#1}\daycount
    \DTMsavejulianday{newDeadLineDate}{\number\daycount}
    \DTMusedate{newDeadLineDate}
 }

\begin{document}

\dateRange{2016}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}

\dateRange{2016}{12}{30}{2016}{12}{31}

\dateRange{2016}{11}{31}{2016}{12}{31}

\dateRange{2015}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Extracting the year, month and day from a named `datetime2` date

As you probably noticed in your code sample where the commands `\DTMsavedate` and `\DTMsavejulianday` are used, the `datetime2` package can save dates in special stores identified by a 〈name〉. Quoting section *Storing and Using Dates and Times* of the `datetime2` manual:

> In the commands below, the 〈name〉 (no active characters) is a name that uniquely identifies the information.

When you have a date in such a store, as is the case after executing `\DTMsavejulianday{〈name〉}{〈number〉}`, you can extract the corresponding year, month and day using the commands `\DTMfetchyear`, `\DTMfetchmonth` and `\DTMfetchday`. Each of these commands takes a 〈name〉 argument and expands to the corresponding number. In other words, `\DTMfetchyear{〈name〉}` expands to the year, `\DTMfetchmonth{〈name〉}` to the month and `\DTMfetchday{〈name〉}` to the day. The rest is essentially plumbing work. :-)

## Connecting the different parts

I propose a `\dateRange` command that behaves like yours, except that:

- it accepts an optional argument (defaulting to 0) that specifies the number of days you want to add to the end date before displaying the resulting range;
- it uses a no-break space between the day ordinal and the month name (`~` is a normal space under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime, but I believe you wanted a no-break space);
- it uses integer comparisons, so that `01` is considered the same as `1`, `02` the same as `2`, etc. for all day, month and year arguments (if you don't want that, use `\str_if_eq:nnTF` as in the first revision of this answer, but I don't see any good reason to do so).

I reindented the function and used `\int_compare:nNnTF` instead of `\str_case:nnF` to make the code easier to read and address the third point above.

I also defined a code-level function `\nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn` to contain this reworked code, because it is much easier to reuse in different situations this way. This allows us to generate a variant `\nebuch_display_date_range:nnnxxx` that fully expands the three last arguments before passing them to the base function `\nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn` (full expansion as done by `\edef`). This only requires a simple line of code:

```latex
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn { nnnxxx }
```

Using the variant, it's easy to pass the result of the temporary date calculation (which adds the offset) to the base function `\nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn`, because `\DTMfetchday`, `\DTMfetchmonth` and `\DTMfetchyear` are all expandable functions (see the documentation of `datetime2`).

The computation of the offset date is also implemented in a code-level function, namely `\nebuch_compute_offset_date:nnnnn`, to make it easily reusable by other code (and it is used in my implementation of `\dateRange`).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[en-GB,calc]{datetime2}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\numdash}{\,--\,}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% Similar to your \dateRange, but we use integer comparisons here and the
% code-level API allows the creation of variants with \cs_generate_variant:Nn.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn #1#2#3#4#5#6
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#4}
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {#2} = {#5}
          {
            \int_compare:nNnTF {#3} = {#6}
              { \DTMdisplaydate {#4} {#5} {#6} {-1} }
              {
                \DTMordinal {#3} {} {} \numdash
                \DTMdisplaydate {#4} {#5} {#6} {-1}
              }
          }
          {
            % I replaced ~ with \nobreakspace here because of \ExplSyntaxOn
            \DTMordinal {#3} \nobreakspace \DTMmonthname {#2} \numdash
            \DTMdisplaydate {#4} {#5} {#6} {-1}
          }
      }
      {
        \DTMdisplaydate {#1} {#2} {#3} {-1} \numdash
        \DTMdisplaydate {#4} {#5} {#6} {-1}
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \nebuch_display_date_range:nnnnnn { nnnxxx }

\newcount \nebuch_tmp_count

% #1, #2, #3: year, month, day
% #4: number of days (offset)
% #5: <name> (in the sense of datetime2) used to store the resulting date
\cs_new_protected:Npn \nebuch_compute_offset_date:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \DTMsavedate { nebuch_compute_offset_date_tmp_date } { #1-#2-#3 }
    \DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday
      { nebuch_compute_offset_date_tmp_date } {#4} { \nebuch_tmp_count }
    \DTMsavejulianday {#5} { \number \nebuch_tmp_count }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \dateRange } { O{0} m m m m m m }
  {
    \nebuch_compute_offset_date:nnnnn {#5} {#6} {#7} {#1}
                                      { nebuch_dateRange_tmp_date }
    \nebuch_display_date_range:nnnxxx {#2} {#3} {#4}
      { \DTMfetchyear { nebuch_dateRange_tmp_date } }
      { \DTMfetchmonth { nebuch_dateRange_tmp_date } }
      { \DTMfetchday { nebuch_dateRange_tmp_date } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dateRange{2016}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange{2016}{12}{30}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange{2016}{11}{31}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange{2015}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}

\bigskip
\dateRange[3]{2016}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange[3]{2016}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{28}\par
\dateRange[3]{2016}{12}{30}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange[3]{2016}{12}{30}{2016}{12}{28}\par
\dateRange[31]{2016}{11}{31}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange[31]{2016}{11}{31}{2016}{11}{30}\par
\dateRange[365]{2015}{12}{31}{2016}{12}{31}\par
\dateRange[365]{2015}{12}{31}{2016}{01}{01}

\bigskip
\dateRange{2016}{02}{7}{2016}{2}{07}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]